# Grunt concat + uglify with sourcemaps

Tags: gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I use concat to merge JS files into one file and uglify to minimize the JavaScript. How can I create a sourcemaps file that uses the source JS files?

My current gruntfile:

```js
concat: {
    options: {
        // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
        separator: ';'
    },
    dist: {
        // the files to concatenate
        src: ['<%= config.src %>/js/**/*.js'],
        // the location of the resulting JS file
         dest: '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.js'
    }
},

uglify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to enable source maps on both the `concat` and `uglify` tasks, and you must specify the `sourceMapIn` option for the uglify task.

Here's a sample grunt config:

```js
concat : {
  options : {
    sourceMap :true
  },
  dist : {
    src  : ['www/js/**/*.js'],
    dest : '.tmp/main.js'
  }
},
uglify : {
  options : {
    sourceMap : true,
    sourceMapIncludeSources : true,
    sourceMapIn : '.tmp/main.js.map'
  },
  dist : {
    src  : '<%= concat.dist.dest %>',
    dest : 'www/main.min.js'
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer has been helping resolve a similar requirement (mapping uglify source to require source to individual require modules). Thanks!

Comment: This is working for me except the line numbers are wrong in the final map when using the minified js (chrome's console will point to line 320 for an error instead of line 290 for example).

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In my case the source maps are generated but unusable. When I set a breakpoint the code does not stop there. Seems like a general problem of uglifyjs that is not solved yet.

Comment: Y0lk, Are you adding a banner that happens to be 30 lines long?

Comment: The `sourceMapIn` can be more conveniently specified as (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207983/how-to-specify-multiple-source-maps-in-uglify-grunt-task): `sourceMapIn: function(path) { return path + ".map"; }` which is more generic and also supports multiple source files.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to the problem that it doesn't stop on breakpoints ? I am having the same issue. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to stop on breakpoints it just doesn't stop.

Answer (score -1):

Per the [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemap) docs, you can enable sourcemap generation as part of the uglify process.

Your uglify config would look something like:

```
uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
            },
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
        }
    },
```

Comment: That is working if I would only use uglify, but I am using both uglify and concat.