# Yeoman Angular source maps concat and minification

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

### Problem

Breakpoints not breaking in browser from source-maps generated using grunt task of `yeoman-angular-generator`. The code has been concatenated and minified.

### What I have tried

I have looked at this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792954/grunt-concat-uglify-with-sourcemaps) for the configuration of the grunt task  and have generated what I think is the correct source-map using the following grunt config:

```
concat : {
  options : {
    sourceMap :true
  }
},
uglify: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapIncludeSources : true,
    sourceMapIn : '.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js.map'
  }
},
```

### What I need help with

Has anyone used the `yeoman-angular-generator` and managed to concat then minify their code and generate source-maps from it? What steps are needed to make it work?

I need to concat and minify my code. Getting source-maps to work with JUST minification is easy or JUST concatenation is also easy but with BOTH concat and minify it seems to not work so well.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this, changing the usemin configuration and adding some properties to the concat/uglify configuration object. But attention, the dist files produced by this options are not good for production!

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {
          js: [{
            name: 'uglify',
            createConfig: function (context, block) {
              var generated = context.options.generated;
              generated.options = {
                stripBanners: true,
                mangle: false,
                sourceMap: true,
                sourceMapIncludeSources: true,
                compress: false,
                beautify: true
              };
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'concat',
            createConfig: function (context, block) {
              var generated = context.options.generated;
              generated.options = {
                //stripBanners: true,
                //mangle: false,
                sourceMap: true,
                sourceMapIncludeSources: true,
                separator: ';',
              };
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn´t really helps. The extra config don´t minify the scripts. Why would you need sourcemaps for non minified code in the first place?